# order by closest time difference in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get records order by closest time difference.

I have calculated the time difference in order by clause, which is causing performance issue, as table has about 2M records.

Note:  *In my actual query, There is no join and table has only 13 columns.*

Take this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([ID] int, [User] varchar(5), [ScheduleOn] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([ID], [User], [ScheduleOn])
VALUES
    (1, 'User1', '2018-01-09 11:50:03.103'),
    (2, 'User2', '2018-01-09 11:38:03.103'),
    (3, 'User3', '2018-01-09 11:42:03.103'),
    (4, 'User4', '2018-01-09 11:45:03.103'),
    (5, 'User5', '2018-01-09 11:43:03.103'),
    (6, 'User6', '2018-01-09 11:44:03.103'),
    (7, 'User7', '2018-01-09 11:40:03.103')
;
```

Here is my sample query.

*ScheduleOn is type of Datetime.*

```
Declare @currentDate datetime = '2018-01-09 11:42:03.103'

select *, ABS(datediff(mi,@currentDate,ScheduleOn)) AS JustToSee from yourtable 

order by ABS(datediff(mi,@currentDate,ScheduleOn))
```

I want to know , is there any other get the records order by closest time difference.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50431/2)

Comment: Please could you list any indexes available, and the execution plan for your sample query.  The root of the performance issue is that you need to apply the calculation to every row and then re-sort every one of those 2M rows.  This is compounded by the `ABS()` which I suspect blinds the optimiser from being able to use any available index.  There are a few options I can think of playing with, but the execution plan may help at least confirm what I believe is the problem.

Comment: Is @currentDate going to be Current Date Time always? or Is it parameter coming from some other table or as user input?

Comment: I can't figure a way of accomplishing this without the execution plan requiring a SORT step *(which is the expensive bit)*.  Can I turn this on its head?  Why do you need this, what are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps a different set of results *(be they smaller, or perhaps differently sorted)* may be able to fulfill the functional requirement that you have?

Comment: Do you really need all 20M results in a result set? If you only needed, say, 10 results then you could separately query for the 10 most recently in the past, the 10 most imminent in the future, union those queries and then apply your filter (that has to be applied row-by-row) to that result to reduce the results futher.

Comment: @Raska : yes. It will always be current date.

Comment: @Amit Kumar, Sorry for one more question - but is it just Current Date or Current Date as well as Time exactly at the moment of running query? Reason for asking - trying to think if adding 'Difference' column and daily batch update is a possibility!

Comment: @AmitKumar Your example includes a Time component in the `@currentDate` variable's value.  If that variable is always "right now", do you therefore have data in the table for the future??  If there is no future dated data, and the variable's value is always now, why do you need the `ABS()`?  If there is future dated data in the table, what does it mean?  Without a better description of the context you will use this in, it may be impossible to supply you with the information you would benefit from the most.

Answer (score 2):

Although you have yet to reply to a question raised in comments, I thought it may be helpful to you or others to see the type of query being alluded to.

The example given is expensive because after the operation of `ABS(DATEDIFF())` the data is considered to be out of order.  This means that sorting the data becomes expensive *(Sorting 2million rows)*.

Where only those rows closest to the @currentDate value are of interest, however, the sample size can be limited before having to apply the sort.

```
WITH
  closest_100_each_side
(
  SELECT TOP(100) *, ScheduleOn - @currentDate AS diff FROM yourTable WHERE ScheduleOn >= @currentDate ORDER BY ScheduleOn ASC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP(100) *, @currentDate - ScheduleOn AS diff FROM yourTable WHERE ScheduleOn <  @currentDate ORDER BY ScheduleOn DESC
)
SELECT TOP(100)
  *
FROM
  closest_100_each_side
ORDER BY
  diff ASC
```

With an appropriate index on `ScheduleOn` the two queries in the CTE become trivial, and the final query now only needs to sort 200 rows to find the closest 100 rows.

This *will* be quicker than simply applying `TOP(100)` to your existing query.

As such it becomes extremely important to understand what the data is for, how it will actually be used after the query has been executed.  That small piece of information may allow a minor change to the query to allow a dramatic performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Well as long as MS SQL `DATETIME` is 2 integers internally you can do it like this:

```
Declare @currentDate datetime = '2018-01-09 11:42:03.103'
Declare @currentDateFloat float = CONVERT(float, @currentDate)

select *, ABS(Cast((@currentDateFloat - ScheduleOn) as Float)) AS JustToSee 
from yourtable 
order by ABS(Cast((@currentDateFloat - ScheduleOn) as Float))
```

But I doubt that it will be faster, becouse i've checked actual execution plan and it's the same to your query.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but you can try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
select *, ABS(datediff(mi,@currentDate,ScheduleOn)) AS JustToSee from 
yourtable )

SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY JustToSee
```

Comment: This is no different, it appears to be an attempt to stop SQL Server calculating the expression twice, but SQL Server doesn't calculate it twice any way...

Comment: @MatBailie Exactly right as to what the attempt was. A bit disappointing to see the downvote, as I clearly meantioned this was a solution in the category "maybe".

Comment: If you delete your answer then you don't take the negative score. 
The reason for the down vote is simply to indicate to other users that the answer is not useful information. It's not a vote against You, it's a rating of the information. As the information is based on a flawed premise we don't want people to learn it. That's what the votes are for.

Comment: Ok, I actually had no idea that this was the purpose, I stand corrected.  :)